# Use static function into the class to return it initialize

Tags: c#, wpf, coding-style

I just have a question about this example.
Use Static function into my class to create the object with the correct type.
Is it a coding standard or just weird ?

```
public partial class Example
{
    public enum enumType
    {
        typeA,
        typeB
    }

    private string type;

    public Example(enumType type)
    {
        if ( type == enumType.typeA)
        {
            this.type = enumType.typeA.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            this.type = enumType.typeB.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static Example CreateAsTypeA()
    {
        return new Example(enumType.typeA);
    }
    public static Example CreateAsTypeB()
    {
        return new Example(enumType.typeB);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that is code smell. For example, why are you creating static methods if you can just call the constructor directly?

Comment: There are several "standards" already being violated by this sample, and while the `static` methods appear to be of little use, they do have the "benefit" of 4 fewer keystrokes for the user. (i.e. `var e = Example.CreateAsTypeA();` instead of `var e = new Example(enumType.typeA);`

Comment: I can maybe give you more information. By my company, a lot more of property are set in each case. Constructor still needs to be public because its a WPF MVVM project and the constructor need to be called. They explain to me the benefit that the different enum stay in the class and are  not accessible from outside and the class can only be initialized in 2 way ( A or B )

Comment: The enum member variable inside the class is inaccessible from outside, but the enum definition is accessible from outside. You can call `return new Example(Example.enumType.typeA)`  So, there is no benefit at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your method should be static.

Because they are essentially constructing a variation of the class, there is no need to store anything about the instance of the object. You method's are more or less constructors, not so much properties. That said, you may want to look into the concept of a static constructor.  Here is a link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors